# What is the best multiplattform IDE to use with CMAKE?

Tags: cmake, ide

I'm trying to set up a multiplattform project using CMake, so its easy to setup on any PC.
Basicly the CMAKE script sets up all settings for the projects and finds all libraries automatically.
But after trying a few IDE's like codeblocks and eclipse it seams like CMake integration in these is pretty lackluster.
Does anybody have a few recommendations for better IDE's?
They should have an included debugger and code completion and should be easy to setup on windows and linux.

Comment: The best IDE is of course KDevelop.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Starting with version 2.6.0 CMake includes a generator for Eclipse CDT 4.0 or newer. It works together with the Makefile generators (i.e. "Unix Makefiles", "MinGW Makefiles", "MSYS Makefiles", and maybe "NMake Makefiles"). This generator creates a set of .project/.cproject files that can be imported in Eclipse using File > Import > Existing Eclipse project.

https://cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator

Comment: Still, some IDEs support editiong CMake files and project re-.generation.

Comment: Very poor integration in eclipse CDT . There is only a nice plugin to edit cmake files named CMakeEd

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at clion, that fully integrates CMake, but I dislike the editor,  not really user friendly.